# Spring security use hasPermission within PreAuthorize with only one parameter

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, acl

How can I call the hasPermission function with just one parameter?

Currently I have something like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('someResource', 'READ')")
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('canReadSomeResource')")
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this? I basically just want to specify the permission that is needed in order to call a method, rather than a resource and a permission.

Answer (score 2):

The specific purpose of `hasPermission()` is to check whether a user is authorized to execute an operation on a particular domain object. If you're wanting to just check whether a user has a certain general-purpose authority, you should use `hasRole()`.

Comment: Ok, is there something other than hasRole()? In my model each role is assigned a set of permissions, and I want to annotate a method requiring the permission. In this way I don't know what roles would be valid, I want to be able to check the roles a user has for a particular permission.

Comment: @user1751547 What authentication provider are you using? The general advice is to make each permission an authority and to add all of them to the user's list.

Comment: I've extended the AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider. The answer to this question seems to suggest I can do what I am trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097152/custom-annotation-with-spring-security  I'm not just sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `hasAuthority('canReadSomeResource')` that checks the user authority to access a resource.

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('canReadSomeResource')")
public void myMethod(){
   ...
}
```

That authority (`canReadSomeResource`) can be provided to the spring security by implementing `UserDetailsService` interface.